How does Visa Retrogression affect my CSPA calculation?
Sorry if this was a repost but I am clueless.
My PD is 8th Jan 2007,
Approval date: 9th June 2009,
DQ date: 21st April 2021.
My PD became current first on Dec 2019 but in February 2020 there was a 7 month retrogression in F4 category. My PD became current again on July 2021.
I am not sure about my CSPA calculation now as I’m confused which year I’ll take as my pd current year?
My DOB is 2000/09/08

Are you doing Adjustment of Status within the US or Consular Processing abroad? Did you apply for Adjustment of Status or submit an immigrant visa application during the period when it was first available (Dec 2019 to Feb 2020)?

If you filed the application for an immigrant visa (if you were outside the US) or for Adjustment of Status (if you were inside the US) during the period when a visa number was available the first time (Dec 2019 to Feb 2020), that would serve to "lock in" your CSPA age calculated based on the date when a visa number became available during that period, eve if visa numbers subsequently became unavailable.
On the other hand, if you didn't file the application while it was current the first time, before it became unavailable again, then your CSPA age is not locked in based on the first time it became available, and will be determined based on the future time when it becomes available again. This means it's possible you will age out even though you wouldn't have aged out if you had filed the application during the first time it was available.
With respect to the requirement to "seek to acquire" a visa within one year of it becoming available, if the first period when a visa number was available was less than a year before it became unavailable, and you didn't "seek to acquire" it during this first period, you will still have another full year to "seek to acquire" it the next time a visa number becomes available (assuming if you haven't aged out, of course).
See 9 FAM 502.1-1(D)(8):

a. An applicant must have one full year of visa availability to seek
to acquire LPR status.  If a visa becomes unavailable within the
one-year period and the applicant does not seek to acquire within that
limited time frame, then the applicant has another full year to seek
to acquire once a visa becomes available again, provided the applicant
is still unmarried and the CSPA age is under 21 at that time.  The
applicant’s age is calculated based on the date that the visa becomes
available again.  A visa may become unavailable because it
retrogresses (moves backward in time) in the Final Action Dates chart
in the Visa Bulletin or because visa numbers become unavailable in a
particular category (indicated by “U” in the Final Action Dates
chart).  A visa may also become unavailable if a petition converts to
a category with a longer wait time (e.g., F1 converts to F3) or if the
petition is revoked (e.g., automatic revocation because of death of
petitioner).
b. If a visa availability date retrogresses or otherwise become
unavailable before the visa had been available for one full year, any
actions taken within one year of the visa becoming available the first
time that satisfy the sought to acquire requirement (see 9 FAM
502.1-1(D)(6)) will be sufficient to lock in the applicant’s CSPA age as of the first day the visa became available during this period,
provided the applicant is still unmarried and the CSPA age is under 21
at that time.

And 7 USCIS-PM A.7(F)(6):

If a visa initially becomes available and then becomes unavailable for
accepting and processing an adjustment of status application before
the potential adjustment applicant has filed an application, the
applicant’s CSPA age is not locked in. When the visa becomes available
again, the applicant’s CSPA age is calculated based on the new visa
availability date. If the applicant’s CSPA age is over 21 at the time
of subsequent visa availability, the applicant is no longer eligible
for CSPA coverage. Therefore, it is always in the applicant’s best
interest to apply for adjustment of status as soon as possible when a
visa first becomes available according to the chart designated by
USCIS so as to lock in the applicant’s CSPA age.

And 7 USCIS-PM A.7(G)(2):

When a visa becomes unavailable to the noncitizen before a continuous
1-year period has elapsed, the applicant has another 1-year period to
seek to acquire when the visa once again becomes available for
accepting and processing an adjustment of status application.

In your case, your petition was pending for 2 years and 5 months. Even if you did not seek to acquire during the first period when a visa number was available, your CSPA age would have been determined based on when it became available the second time, in July 2021. At that time, you were age 20 and 10 months, and, subtracting 2 years and 5 months, your CSPA age would have been 18 and 5 months, which was well below 21.
However, you had one year from the visa number becoming available the second time to "seek to acquire" in order to benefit under CSPA. That one year was over in July 2022. If you didn't perform one of the actions that met the "seek to acquire" requirement by then, it is too late to immigrate as a derivative beneficiary, as you wouldn't be able to use CSPA, and your true age was already over 21.
